# How to link flask with react application ?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, flask

I have part of a website which use Flask (Jinja for templating ) and server side rendering, and I would like to build the second part using a SPA framework like react.

I can't figure out how I can link my flask application with this react app both in development and production .

My folder structure is as follows:

```
-Parent Folder
 -application:
   - __init__.py
   - some python files and database
   - api.py - This is a REST API for the react part to communicate with
   - static:
     - css
     - dashboard
       - React app created here through create-react-app
```

I don't know how I can show the dashboard app which is a react app when user type :  `website.com/dashboard` , this route is defined in my pthon files but I want the whole react app to compile and return the dashboard generated HTML file .

Comment: Why server-side rendering? Why not compile the react resources when you deploy, and just serve the static files? Then it's just another static file you can serve from the route.

Comment: The duplicate does exactly that: serve the built files; just pick a different path from `/` to serve the route.